# Differential equation $xy+y^2y’=6x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this differential equation?
$$xy+y^2y'=6x$$

This is what I’ve tried
$$xy+y^2y'=6x$$
$$xydx+y^2dy=6xdx$$
$$(xy-6x)dx+y^2dy=0$$

Since $(xy-6x)dy=x y^2dx=0$, this isn’t a complete differential equation.
Let $\mu$ be a function of $x,y$

$$\mu(xy-6x)dy=\mu y(xy-6x)+\mu x$$
$$\mu y^2 dx=\mu xy^2$$
$$\mu (xy-6x)dy=\mu y^2dx \implies \mu y(xy-6x)+μx=\mu xy^2$$
If $\mu(x,y)=\mu(x)$
And I can’t go further.

Could you give the direction?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: I see. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y^2 y'+xy =6x $$
Devide by $y^2$ after you test the $y=0$ particular solution and get
$$y'+\frac{x}{y}=\frac{6x}{y^2}$$
Move to the other side and factor $x$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= x\left(\frac{6}{y^2}-\frac{1}{y}\right)$$And this is a sepparable dif eq.
$$ \frac{y^2}{6-y}dy=xdx$$
Perform polynomial division, and integrate both sides now.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I’m sorry to disturb you, but how do you do about y=0?  If I substitute 0 for y, I get 6x=0. Is it ok?

Comment: No, it's not a equality for any real $x$. Thus you just type at the end $y=...$ for $x\neq 0$

Comment: I see! Thank you so much